# Sass CSS - Change Navbar-link color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I want to change the color of my `navbar` on Bootstrap 4 but It doesn't work, I don't understand why. I tried many things, but nothing

Here is the `navbar` with his little CSS

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <div class="nav navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">HearthBreak <span     class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  </div>
</nav>

.navbar{
    background-color: #252830;
    .nav-item, .nav-link{
        color: #FFF;
    }
}
```

Normally I can change the NavItem but I don't understand which child I need to change.

Answer (score 1):

Add a more specific selector like `.navbar.navbar-light.bg-faded` (try to use `!important` **only** as last resort):

```
.navbar.navbar-light.bg-faded{
        background-color: #252830;
        .nav.navbar-nav>a.nav-item.nav-link {
            color: #fff;
        }
    }
```

Snippet below:

```css
.navbar.navbar-light.bg-faded {
  background-color: #252830;
}
.nav.navbar-nav>a.nav-item.nav-link {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <div class="nav navbar-nav">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">HearthBreak <span     class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

the default color for `<a>` tag in bootstrap is blue,you need to override that by using **! important**.I'm added the snippet below.

```css
.navbar{
    background-color: #252830;
    
}
.nav-item, .nav-link{
        color: #FFF ! important;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <div class="nav navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">HearthBreak <span     class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is using `!important` really called for? You can simply use an equally, or more, specific selector.

Comment: @Terry just to overwrite his bootstrap property,is bootstrap have high priority,right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the background-color of navbar, you may have to override "background-image" property as:

```
nav.navbar{
    background-color: red;
    background-image:none;
    .nav-item, .nav-link{
        color: #FFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only the text whch is black, I want to change it to white.